# .htaccess force www and force https for certain path and Concrete5 pretty URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https, concrete5

**edit: This question is now moot as the whole site will be served using HTTPS**

My `.htaccess` is causing a redirect loop.

I need all three sections to work, the purpose of each is in the comment.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force HTTPS for /book unless dev or already there
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^book https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Force www prefix unless dev or already there
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_PROTOCOL}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# Concrete5 pretty URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm having to work on the live server because the certificate is only valid there (with `www.` required).

I've tried many variations of the above, but am stumped, so am hoping fresh eyes on this will help, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd rule isn't looking right as `REQUEST_PROTOCOL` has value of `HTTP/1.1`.

You can use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force HTTPS for /book unless dev or already there
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^book https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Force www prefix unless dev or already there
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www|dev)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# Concrete5 pretty URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a redirect loop. Can you tell me what you're doing differently (aside from the `REQUEST_PROTOCOL` bit) to avoid the loop?

Comment: Did you notice use of condition `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|` and it's back reference `%1`. Test it a new browser to avoid 301 caching. Also tell me what URL are you entering in your browser.

Comment: Thanks. My question has now become moot as we're now changing the whole site to use HTTPS.

Comment: You will still need some light weight rules to force `https` in that case.